# How to change delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have this small code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class monogram3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String name;
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
     System.out.print("Enter your full name (first, middle, last):");
     name = scanner.next( );
     System.out.println("Name entered: " + name);
   }

}
```

---

Expected output:
Enter your full name (first, middle, last): John Stacy Clug
Name entered: John Stacy Clug

Ouput that I'm getting:
Enter your full name (first, middle, last): John Stacy Clug

---

Is there something wrong in code that it is not displaying the full name that I entered? I know there are other methods of doing it but I'm curious to know whats wrong here.

Comment: What output are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: Can you provide us with the example of what you entered and what you got ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question as this information is much too important to hide in comments.

Comment: Have you considered just using `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of messing with your scanner's delimiters?

Comment: Didn't get you? Something wrong in question?

Comment: We've requested more information, and you've posted it in comments down here, a location that 1) does not allow formatted text, and that 2) many don't read. The information is too important to reside down here, and I'm requesting that you [edit] your question (please click on the [edit] link) and improve the question.

Comment: Did you tries to make a print of `System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`. It will possibly print a `white space`

Comment: I've edited my question plz check it.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/uc17K5

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2. DO you think there is some problem with this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should have just used `nextLine` and saved yourself the trouble. The problem you are having is that on Windows (I assume you use Windows), `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is  `\r\n` but System.in separates lines using just `\n` (At least it does when I use Netbeans). As a result, since the console input never actually contains `\r\n`, the line

```
name = scanner.next( );
```

never stops asking for input because it never reaches the delimiter, and so the next line `System.out.println("Name entered: " + name);` never runs. Just use `nextLine()`, okay?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows. Thanx for correcting. Resolved!

Comment: @Ahsok glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question but you are pressing "Enter" after inputting the string correct? The current code worked for me in a reasonable manner. 
Enter your full name (first, middle, last): john e doe
Name entered:  john e doe

Comment: No, I'm entering space after each string.